# Cubic MacLaurin $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find the Cubic MacLurin expansion of e^{x^2}.

First, I tried the sub $t=x^2$ and used the regular expansion for $e^t$. But that was wrong. Can I *not* do non-linear substituions?

My calculations:

> $
> e^t = 1 + t + \dfrac{t^2}{2} + \dfrac{t^3}{3!} + \ldots\\
> t = x^2\\
> e^{x^2} = 1 + x^2 + \dfrac{x^4}{4} + \dfrac{x^6}{6} + \ldots\\
> $
>
> Direct method:
>   $
> \begin{align}
> &f = e^{x^2} & f(0) = 1\\
> &f' = 2xe^{x^2} & f'(0) = 0\\
> &f'' = 2(f'x + f) & f''(0) = 2\\
> &f''' = 2(f''x + f' + f') & f'''(0) = 0
> \end{align}\\
> f(x) = e^{x^2} = 1 + 0 + \dfrac{\not 2}{\not 2!}x^2 \ \leftarrow \text{Correct}\\
> f(x) = f(0) + f'(0) + \dfrac{f''(0)}{2!}x^2 + \dfrac{f'''(0)}{3!}x^3
> $

Comment: Your approach is correct but you have  a mistake with the second term : it is $x^4/2$ and not $x^4/4$. Staynig with the expansion of $e^t$ and replacing $t$ by $x^2$ is the good way. Don't make your life more complex !

Comment: After replacing $t$ by $x^2$, just drop the higher order terms and you get the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

As you are aware already, the Maclaurin expansion of $e^t$ is$$e^t=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2!}+\frac{t^3}{3!}+\cdots$$
Replacing $t$ with $x^2$ gives
\begin{align}e^{x^2}&=1+(x^2)+\frac{(x^2)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x^2)^3}{3!}+\cdots \\ &= 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{6}+\cdots\end{align}

Comment: yes, but I thought that I had to include the $x^4/2$ term as well, but when I do the direct method, it's just the $x^2$ term.

Comment: when you write "cubic" it sounds logical to exclude the x^4. But in my language, it is written "up to and including the third derivative term".

Comment: In the Direct Method, you need to find $\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}$. That is, $$\frac{f^{(4)}(0)}{4!}x^4=\frac{4e^{x^2}(4x^4+12x^2+3)\vert_{x=0}}{4!}x^4= \frac{12}{24} x^4=\frac{x^4}{2}$$ By the way, I used WolframAlpha in finding the fourth derivative.